# Describe all functions which are defined as $f:\mathbb R \to \mathbb R $ and satisfying $f(x)=\frac1{f(x)}$

Tags: analysis

Describe all functions which are defined as $f:\mathbb R \to \mathbb R $ and satisfying $$f(x)=\dfrac1{f(x)}$$

My Attempt:

If $f$ is constant function then.

$$(f(x))^2=1$$

Then $f(x)=1$ or $f(x)=-1$

I cannot think non-constant function satisfying this

What about $f$ being continuous?

Comment: How about $$f(x)=\begin{cases}1&\text{if }x\le 0\\-1&\text{if }x>0\end{cases}$$...?

Comment: This question does not deserve the down votes it has received.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you allow discontinuous functions, then the general solution is that you pick some subset $A$ of $\Bbb{R}$ and define a function $f_A : \Bbb{R} \to \Bbb{R}$ by:

$$
f_A(x) = \left\{\begin{array}{l@{\quad}l} 1 & \mbox{if $x \in A$} \\
-1 & \mbox{if $x \not\in A$}\end{array}\right.
$$

Any solution is $f_A$ for some unique $A$.
The two continuous solutions correspond to $A = \Bbb{R}$ and $A = \emptyset$.

Comment: Why is there any functions other then these, I quite didnt understand the uniqueness

Comment: My point about uniqueness is that $f_A = f_B$ iff $A=B$, so this is a complete description of such functions: every such function is $f_A$ for exactly one set $A$.

Answer (score 2):

$f$ satisfies this equation iff there exists a set $A$ such that $f =2\chi_A-1$. If $f$ is continuous then it is identically $1$ or identically $-1$.

[For the proof define $A$ as $\{x: f(x)=1\}$; $ \chi_A$ is defined by $ \chi_A(x)=1$ if $ x \in A$ and $0$ if $x \notin A$].

Comment: since $f$ defined on whole real line I think characteristic function cannot be the candidate because then 1/0 be not defined

Comment: You mean $2\chi_A - 1$.

Comment: @David: I think Kavi changed the answer in the light of my comment. The comment about $1/0$ was correct  at the time of writing.

Comment: That is true and I am thankful to @RobArthan for pointing out the error in my earlier answer.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:**
$$\begin{align}
&\qquad \quad f(x)=\dfrac1{f(x)} \\
&\implies \frac{f(x)^2-1}{f(x)}=0 \\
&\implies (f(x)-1)(f(x)+1)=0 \end{align}\tag{for all $x$}$$

Comment: Why is the downvote?

Comment: my post is downvote too :(